# APACHE VirtualHosts configuration for Zend project and regular sites

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have such a problem:
In a local network I have a server which is called by its `server_ip`.
I have few sites located under `/www/site_folder` where `index.php` is located.
So whenever `http://server_ip/site_folder` is called `index.php` is called and selected site loads.

Now I put in `/www/zend_site` a Zend project.
It means two things:
1. `index.php` is located under `/www/zend_site/public`,
2. Zend requires rewriting rules set up so framework can understand controller/action extracted from an URL.

What I want, and can't succeed, is to have ability to call Zend project by typing `http://server_ip/zend`, and also to have rest of my simple sites working by calling them by `http://server_ip/site_folder`.

I got familiar with configuration for a Zend http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Server-5-Community-Edition/configuring_zend_framework.htm and tried to make use of virtual hosts by introducing new one called zend.

I see it's not possible to get such two existing options running. If zend is in virtual host and if I call only `sever_ip` it loads zend project instead of `/www/index.php` (a dummy site). If I remove virtual host after I call `http://server_ip/zend` it loads `/www/zend/index.php` instead of `/www/zend/public/index.php` and also site doesn't work (after I created symbolic link to proper index.php), because links are not correctly rewritten with controller/action extraction.

Or maybe I am thinking wrong about VirtualHosts idea? In `server_ip/something` <- something is not a domain which could be used in VirualHost in this case?....

Any idea if my configuration could work?

Regards

Comment: did you try binding the folder /www/zend/public to server_ip/zend ? The reason is, that /www/zend/public should be the DocumentRoot in the vhost configuration. Can you extend your post with the vhost configuration, so it will be easier to understand the problem?

Comment: an example of your attempt at a vhost  might be appropriate. Keep in mind that you will likely require at least one additional vhost for your preexisting docroot sites to make sure that access is maintained. This level of Apache config can get tricky, be patient.